# How to capture unique user sessions in Webmatrix / Razor / ASP.NET Web Pages?

Tags: razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I need to log unique user sessions in Webmatrix / Razor / ASP.NET Web Pages.  Does _appstart  fire just when the app spins up the first time in IIS or does it fire once per unique user hit?  If just once, how do I capture unique user sessions & settings?

UPDATE: I wasn't sure if the Global.asax events were fired under Razor / ASP.NET WebPages. I tested it out and the Session_Start event fires just fine. Question resolved.

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    Dictionary<DateTime, String> d = new Dictionary<DateTime, String>();
    Application.Lock();
    if (Application["d"] != null)
    {
        d = (Dictionary<DateTime, String>)Application["d"];
    }
    d.Add(DateTime.Now, HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID);
    Application["d"] = d;
    Application.UnLock();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked about logging "unique user sessions", which is a little confusing. All sessions are unique, but not all sessions belong to unique visitors. Returning visitors will start new sessions. If you want to keep a count of sessions, you can hook into the Session_Start event in Global.asax. If you want to count unique visitors, use cookies. Set them when a user visits if one hasn't already got a cookie. Ensure that their expiry is some time well into the future. If the visitor hasn't got a tracking cookie for your site, they must be new (or they might have deleted their cookie...)

Comment: I wasn't sure if the Global.asax events were fired under Razor / ASP.NET WebPages.  I tested it out and the Session_Start event fires just fine.  Question resolved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To directly answer your question, _AppStart runs when the first user hits your site. Future users to the site do NOT cause _AppStart to run. There is no specific page or place to put code that runs for each unique user.

What you want to do is take a look at the ASP.Net Session object. In your page, you can store and retrieve data from Session like so:

```
@{
    // Retrieve
    var someSetting = Session["SomeSetting"]
    // Store
    Session["SomeSetting"] = someSetting;
}
```

ASP.Net will take care of making sure that the setting is stored per-browser-instance using Session Cookies. Note that if you're in a Web Farm environment, you'll need something more robust, but when you're talking about a single server, this should be fine.

If you want some more info, here's the official documentation for ASP.Net Session State: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx